# Real Analysis - Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Convergence testing -

Q. How can we prove that $\sum${($\frac{1}{n^{c}}$)} is convergent? (where n $\in$ N, c = constant, c > 1).

Tried proving using Cauchy's Fundamental theorem but could not reach to the solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Added the details for what is needed.

Comment: Please use mathjax to write mathematics!

Answer (score 2):

The function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^c}$ is positive and decreasing on $[1,\infty)$. Hence, by the integral test (proof is easy to understand), the series converges for $c>1$.

Answer (score 0):

If $c>2$, then $\displaystyle\sum_1\frac1{n^c}<\sum_1\frac1{n^2}<1+\sum_2\frac1{n(n-1)}=2$. So the question now remains how to prove its convergence for $c\in(1,2)$.